# "Save button" for image preview

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a website as I describe for you:

When the user opens a page and clicks on the thumbnail image under post title, a preview of that image is displayed.

I want to put a little icon in any corner of the preview for saving the image. This way the user can save the image by clicking on save button.

When I Googled this I found some results and as you can see [here](http://magezz.com/games/god-of-war-2018-cheats-walkthrough-hints/), I made that button. But it won't work correctly and now I'm stuck.

Can you please look and tell me where I am going wrong?

http://magezz.com/games/god-of-war-2018-cheats-walkthrough-hints/

Comment: Most (or rather all modern) browsers have image downloading built in, why have an extra button for that?

Comment: Make sure to post code if you want helpful responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTML5 you can add the attribute 'download' to your links.

```
<a href="/path/to/image.png" download>Save Image</a>
```

Compliant browsers will then prompt to download the image with the same file name (in this example image.png).

If you specify a value for this attribute, then that will become the new filename:

```
<a href="/path/to/image.png" download="AwesomeImage.png">Save Image</a>
```

**UPDATE:** As of spring 2018 this is no longer possible **for cross-origin** `href`**s**. So if you want to create `<a href="https://i.imgur.com/IskAzqA.jpg" download>` on a domain other than imgur.com it will not work as intended. [Chrome deprecations and removals announcement](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations#block_cross-origin_wzxhzdk5a_download)

Comment: Thank you very much that I have become familiar with this property